# What does this formula for speed, age, miles and year mean?

Tags: r

I am an R novice. I came across this formula in some R code: `m.formula <- formula(I(speed^2) ~ (age + I(age^2) + I(log(age)) + miles + I(miles^2) + year))`. I can see that it is defining a formula giving a result in terms of variables speed, age, miles and year, but I do not understand what `I` means and why the left hand side of the formula definition has `speed^2` in parentheses. I would be grateful if someone could explain this formula in simple English! Thanks in advance.

Comment: In R's formulas, `x*y = x + y + x:y` Therefore, `x^2 = x+x+x:x = x`. In order to protect the arithmetic operation, enclose in function `I()`, as in `I(speed^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

`I()` is necessary to evaluate the transformations of your `data` inside a formula. In your case, this means `speed^2` as a function of `age`, `age^2`, `log(age)` etc.

Without the inclusion of `I()`, your `x^2` would be interpreted as `x` (as @ruibarradas mentionned, `x*y` is `x + y + x:y` in `R`'s formula thus `x^2`  is just `x+x+x:x = x`):

For instance,

```r
head(lm(mpg ~  disp, data = mtcars)$model)
                   mpg disp
Mazda RX4         21.0  160
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0  160
Datsun 710        22.8  108
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4  258
Hornet Sportabout 18.7  360
Valiant           18.1  225
```

yields the same model than

```r
head(lm(mpg ~  disp^2, data = mtcars)$model)
                   mpg disp
Mazda RX4         21.0  160
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0  160
Datsun 710        22.8  108
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4  258
Hornet Sportabout 18.7  360
Valiant           18.1  225
```

Comment: And what would happen if you omit the `I`?

Comment: @Edward See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248794/what-does-this-formula-for-speed-age-miles-and-year-mean#comment108353349_61248794).

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes - I know. I was politely asking linog to explain in his answer.

Comment: @e Oh, OK, sorry :).

Comment: I added some elements to get a more complete answer, thanks for the proposition !

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer helped you, you can accept it ([see here for guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))